# Unity Android ARCore object size

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

Anyone know how to make objects smaller in ARCore. The object I am instantiating is gigantic and scaling the prefab down in the editor doesn't seem to help? There are a bunch of child objects to the parent object I am instantiating if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply modifying the instantiated object's transform.localScale should do the trick. Something like:

`GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(myPrefab);
go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);`

Comment: 'localScale' is reflected in the Inspector. I am experiencing the same issue; prefabs are huge despite setting a miniscule scale even in the code.